# Non-public API usage in iOS App?

Tags: ios, binary, app-store-connect

i'm tryng to upload my App to iTunes store but 1 minute after submission i receive this kind of email togheter with an "invalid binary" message in itunes connect.

The app contains or inherits from non-public classes in DikeMobile: NSArray, NSAutoreleasePool, NSBundle, NSCalendar, NSCharacterSet, NSData, NSDate, NSDateFormatter, NSDictionary, NSError, NSException, NSFileManager, NSHTTPCookie, NSHTTPURLResponse, NSIndexSet, NSMutableArray, NSMutableData, NSMutableDictionary, NSMutableString, NSMutableURLRequest, NSNotificationCenter, NSNumber, NSObject, NSOperation, NSRunLoop, NSSortDe...

How can be those API non public? Any help would be apreciated

Comment: How much trouble would it be for you to show us what your classes are and what they subclass? (Just show us the implementation lines.)

Comment: Because this does appear to be a temporary issue with iTunes Connect, I'm voting to close this as being localized to a particular point in time.

Comment: When we're submitting iOS 5 binaries we get the same error re non-public but different objc_* objects.

I suspect it's both for legacy and new apps.

Answer (score 11):

This is getting reported a lot around the internet right now - it looks like Apple has broken something with iTunes Connect this afternoon.

I know that I was able to upload two binaries this morning without issue, but trying to upload two different ones for other apps this afternoon resulted in the same error you are getting.

It seems that Apple has likely broken their validations while modifying iTunes Connect to allow new iOS 5 app submissions.

Comment: same here - they must have broken something

Comment: Well when anyone finds out that it is fixed please toss a post up here. Got the same issue about 30mins ago.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if the problem is solved in version Xcode 4.1, like is said in this post: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21529?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with Xcode version. I resubmit 1:1 the binary which failed yesterday and now it changed to "Waiting for review". So Apple made a backflip on this. Lets wait if the app is going through the certification process - if not I should get a more detailed description.