# Issue:Your app contains non-public API usage?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to submit my app on the App Store but I'm getting this errors in validation:

- Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the errors, correct them, and re-submit your application.
- Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6.
- If you think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's nine-digit Apple ID, along with detailed information about why you believe the above API's were incorrectly flagged, to appreview@apple.com. For further information, visit the Technical Support page at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/.

Please note in the above error, it says "please review the errors, ...". However, there were no errors displayed during the upload process. We have also search the code for the uniqueIdentifier method in code and have not found anywhere it is used.

I'm using the Third party API is Kamcord for Recording video purpose.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `UIDevice uniqueIdentifier` property is deprecated, so that's probably the non-public API usage they are referring to. Make sure you are using the latest version of the third party library that you are referring to. If you are using an older version, it might still call the method. If that doesn't help, contact the developers of the third party library to confirm it's not in their code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this can be a temporary App Store server side error on submission from XCode, as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652943/non-public-api-usage-in-ios-app). You may have already found that it worked a while later.